Rejection sampling to obtain a random sample from a truncated version of a multivariate probability density
Suppose I have a multivariate probability density $f(\mathbf{y}|\boldsymbol{\theta})$ with support $\mathbb{R}^d$ that is analytically tractable, and I know how to randomly sample from $f(\mathbf{y}|\boldsymbol{\theta})$. Would I be able to use rejection sampling to randomly sample from a truncated version of $f(\mathbf{y}|\boldsymbol{\theta})$ with support $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$, which we can denote  $f_\Omega(\mathbf{y}|\boldsymbol{\theta})$?
At the moment, I'm thinking of sampling from $f_\Omega(\mathbf{y}|\boldsymbol{\theta})$ by first sampling from $f(\mathbf{y}|\boldsymbol{\theta})$ and then only keeping samples that lie in $\Omega$. However, I'm wondering if this is resulting in biased sampling for $f_\Omega(\mathbf{y}|\boldsymbol{\theta})$.
I'm intentionally not providing an expression for $f(\mathbf{y}|\boldsymbol{\theta})$ because I'm wondering if, in general, rejection sampling in such a way will result in biased samples for $f_\Omega(\mathbf{y}|\boldsymbol{\theta})$. If so, are there general frameworks (aside from CDF corrections) to randomly sample from truncated version of PDFs that we are able to randomly sample from?

Why not?  What would be the origin of any bias?  You can find myriad examples of this technique here on CV.  The real issue is the efficiency: when the truncation is severe -- a good example would be removing the middle of a standard Normal distribution, say between $Z=-6$ and $Z=6$ -- then you will spend almost all your time rejecting the samples.  (In the standard Normal example, you would accept less than two out of every billion proposals.)  You certainly don't need any special "framework," because all you're doing is testing whether a sample is truncated or not.

Here are relevant posts: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=rejection+truncation

@whuber Thank you for your comments. In my case, the probability of acceptance is $2^{-d}$, so it's ok for small $d$. However, for larger $d$, I may need to consider other related algorithms. I was doubtful about my approach because it seems much simpler than that outlined in the Rejection sampling Wikipedia article. Does the proposed approach seem simpler because our target distribution is a truncated version of our proposal distribution?

@whuber For example, most of the literature on rejection sampling includes some uniform sample (i.e., https://rpubs.com/SteadyStoffel/truncated_sampling). I'm not doing that here, so I feel like what I proposed is skipping a step. Am I, or is what I'm proposing implicitly using some uniform sampling technique?

Re "...seem simpler...truncated:" yes.

No, the method described will not result in biased samples for $f_\Omega(\mathbf{y}|\boldsymbol{\theta})$.
The reasoning is straightforward:

Unbiased Rejection Sampling: The process of rejection sampling fundamentally involves sampling from a proposal distribution and accepting/rejecting based on some criteria. In this case, the criteria are simply whether the sample lies within the region $\Omega$.

Distribution Preservation: By only accepting samples that lie in $\Omega$, you are effectively sampling from the distribution $f(\mathbf{y}|\boldsymbol{\theta})$ restricted to the region $\Omega$. This is equivalent to drawing samples from the truncated distribution $f_\Omega(\mathbf{y}|\boldsymbol{\theta})$.


Efficiency Concerns
As highlighted by whuber, the efficiency of this method can be a significant concern, particularly when the truncation region $\Omega$ is small relative to the entire space $\mathbb{R}^d$. The probability of acceptance in such cases can be extremely low, leading to high computational cost.
Practical Considerations

Acceptance Probability: The acceptance probability $P(\mathbf{y} \in \Omega)$ is given by the integral of the density over the region $\Omega$:
$$
P(\mathbf{y} \in \Omega) = \int_\Omega f(\mathbf{y}|\boldsymbol{\theta}) d\mathbf{y}
$$
If this probability is very low, the method becomes inefficient.

Dimensionality $d$: As the dimension $d$ increases, the acceptance probability $P(\mathbf{y} \in \Omega)$ typically decreases exponentially, making rejection sampling impractical for high-dimensional spaces with severe truncation.


Alternative Methods
For scenarios where rejection sampling becomes inefficient due to high dimensionality or severe truncation, consider the following alternatives:
1.Importance Sampling: This involves drawing samples from a different proposal distribution that is easier to sample from and then reweighting the samples to correct for the difference between the proposal and target distributions.
2. Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC): Methods like the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm can be adapted to sample from truncated distributions. By constructing a Markov chain that has the truncated distribution as its equilibrium distribution, you can effectively sample from $f_\Omega(\mathbf{y}|\boldsymbol{\theta})$.
3. Slice Sampling: This is particularly useful for sampling from complex distributions and can be adapted to handle constraints imposed by truncation.
Summary

Unbiased Sampling: The rejection sampling method described will not introduce bias when sampling from the truncated distribution $f_\Omega(\mathbf{y}|\boldsymbol{\theta})$.
Efficiency Concerns: The main issue with this approach is its potential inefficiency, especially in high-dimensional spaces or with severe truncation.
Alternative Methods: For better efficiency, consider alternative methods like importance sampling, MCMC, or slice sampling.


Thank you for your very detailed response (again). I appreciate you not only answering my question but also providing some alternative methods that may be more efficient. I'll look into slice sampling a bit more. I only skimmed the surface of that method.
